# iODBC error trying to connect to MS SQL Server in PHP with unixODBC/FreeTDS

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I am trying to connect to a remote MS SQL Server db from PHP on Mac (eventually on an Ubuntu server( with FreeTDS and unixODBC, but even though I seem to have everything set up properly, I'm getting iODBC errors, and I'm not sure how to get around them.

I'm using MacPorts, so my config is:

/opt/local/etc/freetds.conf::

```
[bti_db]
host = 123.45.67.89 (IP address changed to protect the innocent)
port = 14333
tds version = 8.0
```

/opt/local/etc/odbcinst.ini:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = TDS Driver (Sybase/MSSQL)
Driver = /opt/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /opt/local/lib/libtdsS.so
FileUsage = 1
```

/opt/local/etc/odbc.ini:

```
[bti_dsn]
Driver = FreeTDS
Description = My Database
Trace = no
Servername = bti_db
Database = btidata
```

However, whenever I try to connect with odbc_connect() using the 'bti_dsn'

```
$conn = odbc_connect('bti_dsn;, $user, $pw);
```

I get this error:

Warning: odbc_connect() [function.odbc-connect]: SQL error: [iODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified. Driver could not be loaded, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect

In the ODBC section my phpinfo(), I see ODBC Library defined as iodbc, and PHP is compiled with '--with-iodbc=/usr', so I'm guessing that config is my problem.  How can I get around this so that it uses unixODBC/FreeTDS I have set up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[iODBC](http://www.iodbc.org/) is installed by default as part of Mac OS X; has been since Jaguar (10.2.x).  There's no need for UnixODBC on Macs, and it can lead to lots of errors if you're not a serious expert.  There is a specific guide to using [PHP with iODBC on Mac OS X](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/iodbc/wiki/iODBC/IODBCPHPHOWTOMacOSX).  For best results, you may also want to upgrade to the latest [iODBC for Mac OS X](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/iodbc/wiki/iODBC/Downloads#Mac_OS_X).

`/opt/local/etc` should *not* be added to your `$PATH`, through `.profile` or otherwise.

PHP is definitely finding iODBC before UnixODBC, but this should not be a problem; UnixODBC and iODBC are generally (and are meant to be fully) API-equivalent ODBC driver managers.  If you're really concerned about that part, you can change the `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (Mac OS X's version of Linux's `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) -- but if PHP was linked against the iODBC Frameworks, as opposed to the dylibs, this won't make any difference.

(Note that `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` also must include `/opt/local/lib` or your FreeTDS driver won't load.)

For the specific error your report -- PHP needs to have a couple of environment variables set, if you're not using the Mac's default ODBC configuration files (System level are in `/Library/ODBC/odbc[inst].ini`; User level are in `~/Library/ODBC/odbc[inst].ini` ... if there are `~/.odbdc[inst].ini` files present, they should be blended into the `~/Library/ODBC/` files and replaced by symlinks to the same).

If you don't want to use iODBC, or don't want to use those default files, you have to set `$ODBCINI` to target the `odbc.ini` file where you've defined your DSN, and `$ODBCINSTINI` to target the `odbcinst.ini` file which registers the driver you want to use.

Assuming you want to do all of the above, lines like these should be added to your `*.php` files (optimally via a `require` or `include` statement to minimize future editing) --

```
putenv("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/odbcsdk/lib;$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH");
putenv("ODBCINSTINI=/path/to/odbcinst.ini");
putenv("ODBCINI=/path/to/odbc.ini");
```

I can't be exact about the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` setting, because you didn't specify where your UnixODBC libraries are.  However, if you are OK with iODBC being the driver manager, and just want your FreeTDS libraries to load, the following should work --

```
putenv("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib;$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH");
putenv("ODBCINSTINI=/opt/local/etc/odbcinst.ini");
putenv("ODBCINI=/opt/local/etc/odbc.ini");
```

I hope this helps.

P.S. In your DSN definition, this line --

```
Driver = FreeTDS
```

-- should be rewritten.  Either the human-friendly driver name should be wrapped in braces (`{FreeTDS}`), or the full-path to the driver library (`/opt/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so`) should be the value instead.

```
Driver = {FreeTDS}
Driver = /opt/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
```

I'm presuming that you also have something like the following index entry in your `odbcinst.ini` --

```
[ODBC Drivers]
FreeTDS = Installed
```

-- and something like the following index entry in your `odbc.ini` --

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
bti_dsn = FreeTDS
```

...but now I notice that your $conn line may just need correction.  Look at the arguments to `odbc_connect`.

```
$conn = odbc_connect('bti_dsn;, $user, $pw);
```

That should probably look more like --

```
$conn = odbc_connect("bti_dsn", "$user", "$pw");
```

Comment: The ; in the odbc_connect was a typo in the post, not in the code itself.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick.  Here's what I did:
Added [ODBC Data Sources] to odbc.ini, since I didn't have that,
Added [ODBC Drivers] to odbcinst.ini, since I didn't have that, either.
Changed value for driver in [bti_dsn] to /path/to/libtdsodbc.so
Added putenv("ODBCINSTINI=/opt/local/etc/odbcinst.ini");
 and putenv("ODBCINI=/opt/local/etc/odbc.ini"); to my script.

Works like a charm.

Thanks a ton.

Comment: I don't have the /opt directory and I can't find the odbc.ini or odbcinst.ini files. What can I do? I have libtdsodbc.0.0.0.so in my MAMP directory (I think this is the one I compiled myself and copied to the MAMP Library directory (/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/)). Can it be that they don't come by default with MacOSX?

Comment: PS: I followed this instructions with no luck (using PHP 5.3.6 and FreeTDS 0.82): http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/mssql+mamp+php+mac+osx

Comment: @GarciaWebDev - the instructions you say you followed do not get into ODBC connectivity at all. those are focused on MSSQL-specific PHP connections and coding, and won't map well here.

I suggest you ask your own new question, and provide as much information as possible so people can respond usefully...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not looking in your odbc.ini file. Maybe it's looking for `/etc/odbc.ini` and `/etc/odbcinst.ini`?

Comment: Well, before I realized that there were MacPorts for those, I had installed them directly, and they were under /usr/local/unixODBC-2.3.0/etc, and I had the same problem.  Do you think it might just be a matter of adding /opt/local/etc to my path?

Comment: OK, I added /opt/local/etc to my path in .profile and restarted, but I still get the same error.

Comment: TallTed has the answer. OSX specific paths. :-)