# unixODBC error "/usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32"

Tags: php, centos, freetds, unixodbc

I am working on a site where I need to import data from a remote MS SQL Server database into a MySQL database on a Unix server via PHP.  Thanks to answers to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252549/iodbc-error-trying-to-connect-to-ms-sql-server-in-php-with-unixodbc-freetds), I was able to get everything up and running on my dev environment (Mac OS X 10.6).  Now, however, I'm trying to get my server environment set up, which is CentOS 5.4.  I have unixODBC and FreeTDS installed and configured, but when I try to connect, I get the following error:

`Connection Failed:[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so.0' : /usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32`

From what I've been able to find on the internets, it seems that I have 32 bit unixODBC (or FreeTDS, I'm not sure) installed (libtdsodbc.so.0 is symlinked to libtdsodbc.so.0.0.0) and it needs to be 64 bit.  Is that correct?  If so, how do I upgrade to 64 bit version?  I'm a developer, not a server guru, so this is a bit outside of my server knowledge.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the reference in odbcinst.ini from `/usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so.0` to `/usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0` fixed this error for us in the same configuration as you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Your diagnosis is correct. There is no need to upgrade however, since the two can be installed in parallel.

```
yum install freetds.x86_64
```

Comment: When I run the command above, I get the following message: "Package freetds-0.64-11.el5.centos.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do."  Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

This fix didn't work for me. I did install `freetds.x86_64` as well (it let me install but reported conflicts) and the path `./usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so.0` was correct. Created a symbolic link anyway in case internals would be looking for it.

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so.0 /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
```

I originally followed the [instructions at MediaTemple](http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/%28dv%29%3aConnect_to_remote_MS-SQL_databases_through_PHP), but have seen other articles for Cent OS on 64-bit. Will report back if I find anything that works for me.

Indeed, removing FreeTDS, restarting Apache, installing the 64-bit package mentioned above and updating the odbcinst.ini path, I was able to get past the above error, and in fact, remove errors.

I am now successfully "talking" to the MS SQL server, although it is now giving me generic errors. *sigh*. Anyway, got most of the way there. Hope this helps someone.